# Nuxt Auth module redirecting to /home, also using :3000 port

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a `nuxt/laravel` backend setup going where I use the `nuxt` auth module to authenticate the client.

I have set up my `nuxtconfig.json` with

```
auth : {
    watchLoggedIn : false
}
```

After logging in and any subsequent page refresh/calls the module is trying to redirect me to localhost/home (even though I am running on `localhost:3000`

I also tried setting my redirect paths for the local strategy to / but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I realized the redirect was happening from the /user request onto the Laravel backend which resulted in 302 redirect